# Install gstreamer with aws-s3-gst plugin on amazon linux 2023

Tags: amazon-web-services, gstreamer

I'm struggling to install gstreamer with [amazon-s3-gst-plugin](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-s3-gst-plugin) on Amazon Linux ec2.
I managed to install gstreamer with Homebrew, but when I try to build the plugin, it says:

> Run-time dependency gstreamer-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
> Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to build a plugin with meson build according to the documentation.

Did someone manage to install both on Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue. To make th packages installed by homebrew available for pkg-config, I ran the following command before the build:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/pkgconfig"
```